# Flash Builder (Flex) ANT build and Debug

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, ant

I'm trying to use ANT with Flash Builder 4 to compile and debug.
The compiling is the easy part but having trouble to get the debugger to work.

**I want to use ANT to Debug SWF file inside Flash Builder**, so that breakpoints, console traces and everything works as it should.

My script so far. Builds The *.as to *.swf and moves from bin-debug to deploy folder. **How can I start a Flash Builder Debugger for the created SWF?**

```
<target name="Compile level 1">
    <antcall target="compile flex file">
        <param name="file" value="GameOffice"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="open player">
        <param name="file" value="GameOffice.swf"/>
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="compile flex file">
    <mxmlc file="${SRC_DIR}/${file}.as" output="${BUILD_DIR}/${file}.swf" 
        actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8" 
        keep-generated-actionscript="true" 
        incremental="true" 
        static-link-runtime-shared-libraries="true"
        show-actionscript-warnings="true"
        failonerror="true"
        debug="true"
        optimize="false">

        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml" />
        <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" />

        <compiler.include-libraries dir="${basedir}/libs" append="true">
            <include name="HelloThereLibGames.swc" />
            <include name="HelloThereLibStructure.swc" />
            <include name="HelloThereLibUtils.swc" />
        </compiler.include-libraries>

        <metadata description="Hello There Production">
            <contributor name="Fredrick Bäcker" />
        </metadata>

    </mxmlc>
    <copy todir="${DEPLOY_DIR}" file="${BUILD_DIR}/${file}.swf"/> 
</target>
```

Answer (score 3):

I did a 1 try one hit on google: http://blogs.4point.com/armaghan.chaudhary/2009/04/remote-debugging-using-flex-builder-ide.html

I do not get why you would want to build with ant inside flashbuilder. Seems like crossing the stream for water?

IMHO automated build scripts belong in CI environments like hudson. I consider it doing myself a favor, letting my development environment handle the fuzz of local builds and debugging.

Anyways, best of luck

Comment: The main problem I got is that Flex ignores the bin-debug folder when working with SVN. Using a large team of art directors that works inside FLA files, copy writers, game designers and level designers working in XML files. And of course the developers inside the actual code. All of these users need access to the latest bin-debug files but they don't need to use a development tool thats CPU heavy.

So that's why we use another folder for deploy where everyone can publish swf files and work directly in xml files. Problem here is for the developers that need the deploy files inside bin-debug.

Comment: So either set the output directory to be another than bin-debug or remove bin-debug from the ignore list of whatever svn plugin you are using in eclipse( flex builder) or do the commits from the library with either command line or your favorite svn client?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working off a local web server, you can simply open the debug socket in Flash Builder by setting your debug launch config to a blank html page (eg. about:blank) and then opening your browser to your localhost (or whatever url you've set up).

In this case you would run the build with ant, hit debug to open the socket, then switch over to your web browser and load localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this answer is probably a little late, but better late than never!

Is pretty simple really when you know how.  I did a blog entry on it a while back that should show you how:

http://blog.tiltdigital.com/flex/running-flash-builder-4-in-debug-mode-from-apache-ant/

Basically you just need to add an Ant Builder to Flash Builder 'Builders' properties in your project properties.  You can then use that to compile/debug using your build script as you'd normally do using the Flash Builder Compiler/Debugger.

Comment: Your link is giving me 404. It seems that now the correct one is: http://blog.tiltdigital.com/blog/2010/06/08/running-flash-builder-4-in-debug-mode-from-apache-ant/